# php mail using sendmail.exe

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

I am using `XAMPP` on a localhost windows `VISTA` m/c...using gmail as smpt server

I am trying to send an email using simple PHP script

here is the configuration details on `sendmail.ini` (I have the `sendmail.exe` and the other 2 dll in that directory)

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=localhost

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=xxxxxxx
auth_password=xxxxxx

hostname=localhost

and I have changed the php.ini

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = xxxxx

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

and Once I call the script it goes into waiting...for localhost...
here is the debug.log...

> 09/05/02 17:34:41 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** To: xxx@yahoo.com
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** Subject: Form Submission Results
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** From: My Web Site  
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** Reply-To: xxx@gmail.com
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** 
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** Name: xxx
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** E-Mail: xxx@yahoo.com
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** Message:                 hey test message
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** 
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** 
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:465
>   09/05/02 17:34:41 ** Connected.

I am new to `PHP` and would like to know if there is a better way to do mail...I am not in for HTML/multipart mails with attachment now...
Also i should be able to test in localhost without `SMTP` server installed . I would like to use `GMAIL` for now testing.
THnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a library e.g. [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/index.php). Here is their [gmail example](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail).

Another good library (which I haven't used) is [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Here is their [gmail example](http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/connections/smtp).

Answer (score 0):

GMAIL needs SSL afaik.

Of free (and probably "good") php mail libraries i know [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) and [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should also check with your ISP. A lot of them block port 25 to prevent spam.

Answer (score 0):

### **Send Email - GMAIL**

1) Stop Server.

2) Change this lines

**[XAMPP -> PHP -> php.ini]**

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**[XAMPP -> SENDEMAIL ->sendmail.ini]**

```
smtp_port=587 
auth_username= xxxx@gmail.com 
auth_password= xxxx 
smtp_ssl=auto
```

3) Run Server

4) Send email test

```
<?php $to      = 'youremail@xxxx.com'; $subject = 'Test Email
 Email'; $message = 'Hello'; $headers = 'From:
 test@test.com' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: test@test.com' . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 echo print_r(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers),true); ?>
```